# The phone's itself sms app gets disabled when my app set to default

Tags: java, android

in android +API19: I made a SMS app and i just need to receive a sms in it but when my application is set as default, the phone's itself sms app gets disabled and can not send message. The only thing that i need is to receive a message.
But because of that the message app of phone gets disabled and a message can not be sent, guide please, what could i do?
i just need to receive sms!

```
<receiver
        android:name=".ReceiverSms"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        android:enabled="true"
         >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999999">
            <action  android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

code:

```
public class ReceiverSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        HelperWork.toastShower(context, "Runned");

        boolean pswDare = true;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }
        Object[] smsExtras = (Object[]) extras.get(SmsConstant.PDUS);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri smsUri = Uri.parse(SmsConstant.SMS_URI);
        String body = null;
        String address = null;
        for (Object smsExtra: smsExtras) {
            byte[] smsBytes = (byte[]) smsExtra;
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(smsBytes);
            HelperWork.toastShower(context, body);
            body = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

            // do other somthing
        }
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SmsConstant.COLUMN_ADDRESS, address);
        values.put(SmsConstant.COLUMN_BODY, body);
        Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(smsUri, values);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the [android developer's blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

> Other apps that only want to read new messages can instead receive the **SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION** broadcast intent when a new SMS arrives. However, only the app that receives the **SMS_DELIVER_ACTION** broadcast (the user-specified default SMS app) is able to write to the SMS Provider defined by the android.provider.Telephony class and subclasses.

So if you only want to receive SMS, then only use **SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION** and remove **SMS_DELIVER_ACTION**. You don't have to make your app default in order to only receive SMS.

Comment: yes, thanks! and Is there a way to delete a SMS without set to default program and from root! or send sms from root?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you have to set your app to default sms app in order to send/delete sms in Kitkat.